# Как добавить автоскролл слайдеру на Bootstrap?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap, прокрутка

Есть слайдер на Bootstrap.
Как добавить ему автоматическое вращение желательно без jQuery?

```html
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-slide-to="3" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active" id="slide1">

    </div>
    <!-- end item -->

    <div class="item" id="slide2">

    </div>
    <!-- end item -->

    <div class="item" id="slide3">

    </div>
    <!-- end item -->

    <div class="item" id="slide4">

    </div>
    <!-- end item -->
  </div>
  <!-- carousel-inner -->

</div>
<!-- end myCarousel -->
```

Comment: Вообще у бутсртаповской карусели [пример есть][1], но без jQuery оно работать не будет.

VМожет вам подумать о другой реализации?



  [1]: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: да нет, все очень просто) достаточно добавить атрибут data-ride="carousel"

Answer (score 2):

Простой скрипт Вам в помощь:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
      interval: 1200
    })
  });
</script>
```

Либо в Вашем HTML немного подправьте первую строку, добавив атрибут 'data-interval', получим нижеследующее:

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="1200">
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но я уже давно ответил на свой вопрос строчкой выше)

Comment: Не заметил комментария, возможно кто-то воспользуется и этим...